# HapiJS & MySQL crashes after a while

Tags: mysql, node.js, hapi.js

My `HapiJS` + `MySQL` server keeps crashing after a larger number of requests.

```
const MySQL= require('mysql');
const pool = MySQL.createPool({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'aUser',
      password : 'aPWD',
      database : 'DB'
    })};

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    query = 'SOMETHING';

    connection.query(query,function (error, results, fields){
                connection.release();
                reply(results);

    });

});
```

My feeling is the error happens because the pool runs out of connections? 
It fails because `connection` is not defined.

Here's the error:

```
at /home/user/backend/dataPortal/modules/flexible.js:30:14
    at Handshake.onConnect (/home/user/backend/dataPortal/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:58:9)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at Handshake.runBound [as _callback] (domain.js:293:12)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/home/user/backend/dataPortal/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:86:24)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/user/backend/dataPortal/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:105:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/user/backend/dataPortal/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/user/backend/dataPortal/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:75:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/user/backend/dataPortal/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/backend/dataPortal/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
```

Comment: I am facing same issue, got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got solved my problem by adding `socketPath` with the value `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` to the database configurations

```
 const MySQL= require('mysql');
    const pool = MySQL.createPool({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : 'aUser',
          password : 'aPWD',
          database : 'DB',
socketPath:'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
        })};

    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        query = 'SOMETHING';

        connection.query(query,function (error, results, fields){
                    connection.release();
                    reply(results);

        });

    });
```

This may help someone wit same problem [reference](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/8246)